# android:useEmbeddedDex not found when trying to incorporate into project manifest file

Tags: android, configuration, dex

I'm trying to add android:useEmbeddedDex into my project like https://developer.android.com/topic/security/dex describes.

Where I put `android:useEmbeddedDex="true"` in the application manifest file and then add

```
aaptOptions{
    noCompress 'dex'
}
```

into the build.gradle file for my application.

However, when I try to build the project this error is thrown: "AAPT: error: attribute android:useEmbeddedDex not found."

I feel like I'm missing something crucial but I'm not sure what it exactly is. Any help would be appreciated.

AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<manifest>
...
  <application
    ...
    android:useEmbeddedDex="true">
```

build.gradle looks like this:

```
...
android{
  ...
  aaptOptions{
    noCompress 'dex'
  }
}
```

my compileSdkVersion is 28

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion`?

Comment: my compileSdkVersion is 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [embedded DEX documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/dex) you linked:

> On devices running Android 10 (API level 29)

`android:useEmbeddedDex` was only introduced in API level 29. You must update your `compileSdkVersion` to at least 29 to use new attributes introduced in API 29.